# Cookie Authentication with ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Web API

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, restful-authentication

I totally understand if someone finds that my question is very basic or might not make a lot of sense all the way. 
I am new to this and I am trying to use the latest .NET Framework 5 with MVC 6 in order to build a Web Api that could be used from an Angular JS client-side. This will allow me to create a website for it, as well as a mobile application by wrapping it with Phonegap. So please bear with me a bit.

What I am trying to achieve for the moment is to have a Web API controller that receives a login request and returns a result to the client based on Cookie Authentication (later the client should store this cookie and use it for communications with the server)

- I added the following in the project.json

[image]

- In the Startup.cs, I added under ConfigureServices:

  ```
  // Add entity framework support
  services.AddEntityFramework()
      .AddSqlServer()
      .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      {
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
      });

      // add ASP.NET Identity
      services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
          options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
          options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
          options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
          options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
          options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
      })
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
  ```
- In the Startup.cs, under Configure:

  ```
      // Using the identity that technically should be calling the UseCookieAuthentication
      app.UseIdentity();
  ```

Now, in the Controller method to login, I am able to find the user using its email address and the UserManager:

```
            // Verify that the model is valid according to the validation rules in the model itself. 
            // If it isn't valid, return a 400 Bad Request with some JSON reviewing the errors
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // Find the user in our database.  If the user does not exist, then return a 400 Bad Request with a general error.
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", INVALID_LOGIN_MESSAGE);
                return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // If the user has not confirmed his/her email address, then return a 400 Bad Request with a request to activate the account.
            if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Account not activated");
                return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // Authenticate the user with the Sign-In Manager
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            // If the authentication failed, add the same error that we add when we can't find the user
            // (so you can't tell the difference between a bad username and a bad password) and return a 400 Bad Request
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", INVALID_LOGIN_MESSAGE);
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
            }

            return Ok();
```

The problem is happening at the line:

```
            // Authenticate the user with the Sign-In Manager
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

it is throwing the following error:

> Error: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application

I am currently blocked and I searched googled for almost every possible token I could think of and tried multiple solution still in no vain. Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

Ok I finally figured it out after writing this whole question and I wanted to share the answer to avoid the hussle for someone else if they commit the same mistake I did!

The problem was that in the Configure in Startup.cs, I called "app.UseIdentity()" after calling "app.UseMVC()". The order should have been inversed. I donno if this is common knowledge or I should have read about it somewhere.

Comment: That's like an unsaid rule that one is "supposed" to know when dealing with an owin like pipeline. Most of these things have been obscured for a long time and now because of the pipeline model they are obvious.